# Where can I find fixture presets of different materials?

Tags: box2d, chipmunk, box2d-iphone, bulletphysics, jbox2d

Where can I find fixture presets, that can be used in rigid body physics engines, like [Box2D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box2D) to simulate the behaviour of different materials?

I'm looking for values of density, friction and restitution for common materials like:

- Smooth/rough metal
- Wood
- Rubber
- Plastic

Is there a method beside trial and error of setting these values to achieve realistic results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- For 'density rubber', see *[Densities of Miscellaneous Solids](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/density-solids-d_1265.html)*.
- For 'friction table', see *[Coefficient of Friction](http://engineershandbook.com/Tables/frictioncoefficients.htm)*.
- For 'rubber restitution', see *[Coefficients of Restitution](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2006/restitution.shtml)*.